# Add a JIRA link to karate/cucumber report

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd, karate, cucumber-serenity

While using Serenity with JBehave addition of @Title renders a link to JIRA.

Is there a way to add a `Meta @issue #<jira number>`?

The other way could be integrating the existing Serenity @Title as a gherkin syntax dsl with Karate?

Before I get on this path, wanted to know if there is an inbuilt way which I might have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Dev of Karate here. I guess you mean the cucumber-reports-plugin.

First: I have never experimented with rendering links, but it looks doable, for e.g refer to this thread: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/610

Second: Karate has enhanced cucumber tags so that name-value-pairs are supported, so even within a test you would be able to grab the value of a tag, here is an example: [`tags.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/tags.feature).

In current state of Karate you can certainly get the value of the tag and generate a hyperlink. Rendering a hyperlink into the HTML report may need some digging.